# MVC 5 - Bootstrap 4 - Modal full(ish) width not working

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

Within a view the following modal is defined

```
 <div id="PopupModalDocuments" class="modal fade in out">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Document Viewer</h4>
                <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="ModalBody">
                <iframe id="modalFrame" runat="server" seamless="seamless" height="400" style="width: 95%; max-height: 800px;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is overridden like this

```
 #PopupModalDocuments {
        top: 5% !important;
        bottom: 5% !important;
    }

     .modal-lg {
        width: 90% !important;
        }

    #PopupModalDocuments .modal-body {
         max-height: 800px !important;
        }
```

using either modal-lg or the modal ID (that worked in the prior bootstrap version), or a combination of both but still it looks like this (a pdf that is not readable)
[image: Modal Popup]

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
.modal-lg {
        width: 90% !important;
    }
```

to

```
 .modal-lg {
        max-width: 90% !important;
    }
```